# What is a situation where the CSS bolder can be used properly?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have been seeing the `bolder` font-weight value mentioned across the internet for years, but I have never seen it actually used. I can't change the text that is displayed from either the `initial` or `bold` in any situation I have played around with when making websites.

Using Chrome, I have tried making a page with all the font-weight values displayed in 14 different paragraphs. I had them in the order: `initial`, `lighter`, `normal`, `bold`, `bolder`, `100`, `200`, `300`, `400`, `500`, `600`, `700`, `800`, and `900`.

The `initial`, `lighter`, `normal`, `100`, `200`, `300`, `400`, and `500` all look the same (not bold).

The `bold`, `bolder`, `600`, `700`, `800`, and `900` all look the same (bold).

What would be a situation that using `font-weight: bolder` would actually cause the text to display more bold than `font-weight: bold`?

Comment: FYI, the initial value of font-weight is normal, so initial is equivalent to normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`font-weight: bolder` is used to set the next level of boldness above the base weight. This is useful if you are already using a bold font, but the font family supports a bolder weight. For example `Open Sans` (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans) supports 10 weights. If your base font is `Open Sans Bold` `font-weight: bolder` will kick it up to `Open Sans Extra-Bold` if it's available. Or if you are using `light` it will kick it up to normal, etc.

Here's a fiddle that shows one example in practice:

https://jsfiddle.net/zv03Lf5v/3/

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800');

p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
}

p span {
  font-weight: bolder
}

p.lighter {
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Open Sans <span>Bolder</span>
</p>

<p class="lighter">
  Open San Light <span>Bolder</span>
</p>
```

You can see that as you change the parent, the `bolder` version changes in relation.

Answer (score 3):

The font itself needs to support that weight.

Many fonts support only 400/Normal, 500/Medium and 700/Bold; sometimes only 400 and 700.

Besides, `bolder` and `lighter` is not an absolute value, it's relative to the parent. [Click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight).

Comment: What would be a font that actually supports more than the default 2 variants?

Comment: The one I know that supports many weights is [FF DIN](https://www.fontfont.com/fonts/din#tab-overview). It's a paid one, but I'm sure you can find somewhere free fonts that supports many weights.

Answer (score 1):

**font-weight:bolder** and **lighter** works with respect to its **parent's element** font-weight.